# In SharePoint Online, is it possible to filter a standard View based on the documents that specific group(s)/user(s) have been granted access to?

Tags: permissions, filter, metadata, sharepoint-views

I'll be creating sensitive financial documents for 20 locations worldwide.  I'll stop inheriting permissions and granting permissions at the file level.  I would like the permissions I grant for each document to drive what is displayed in the View of each location.  How can I make that happen? I tried the metadata 'Shared With' but it's not working, it doesn't seem to be the one I need. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know using out of the box features are not allowing you for that. There are multiple 3rd Party solution providers that allow you for something similar.

Comment: Can you name a few 3rd party solutions?